# Android Google Maps GeoJson, how to tint the whole map one color

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, geojson

I'm currently working with the Android Google Maps utility library. I receive geojson of a given area via an API call and need to display this area on the map.

I do so by calling

```
GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(getMap(), geoJsonData);
layer.addLayerToMap()
```

where getMap() returns a GoogleMap object and geoJsonData is a JSONObject. 
This code draws a border around the area associated with the geojson.

The code below draws a red border around the area and fills it with yellow.

```
GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(getMap(), geoJsonData);            
GeoJsonPolygonStyle polygonStyle = layer.getDefaultPolygonStyle();
polygonStyle.setStrokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));
polygonStyle.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yellow));
layer.addLayerToMap();
```

**I'm running into trouble trying to style this GeoJsonLayer where the whole map is yellow, the border of the area is red, and the fill color of the area is normal color.**

Can someone tell me how to achieve this in Android using the GeoJson data? 
One option is to create my own polygon shape. I can declare a polygon using coordinates that cover the whole map, and i add a hole using the coordinates returned from the geojson.

But I'm thinking there has to be something simpler that allows me to use the built in GeoJsonLayer class and won't require me to parse the geojson myself.

Comment: If you need yellow background for entire map you can use styling wizard as described in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling. And after that style your GeoJSON polygons with different color.

Comment: @xomena I'm not sure if that helps me achieve what I want. 
I was hoping for something like this in Android https://github.com/vasile/geomask
Using my geojson data.

Answer (score 9):

You can use same approach as you described:

> "declare a polygon using coordinates that cover the whole map, and i
>   add a hole using the coordinates returned from the geojson"

GeoJSON also supported [Polygon with "holes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON#Geometries) so, for GeoJSON with "whole map" coordinates like

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -179.99,
              89.99
            ],
            [
              -179.99,
              0
            ],
            [
              -179.99,
              -89.99
            ],
            [
              0,
              -89.99
            ],
            [
              179.99,
              -89.99
            ],
            [
              179.99,
              0
            ],
            [
              179.99,
              89.99
            ],
            [
              0,
              89.99
            ],
            [
              -179.99,
              89.99
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              -0.191208,
              51.509869
            ],
            [
              -0.158464,
              51.513287
            ],
            [
              -0.151769,
              51.50554
            ],
            [
              -0.174471,
              51.502178
            ],
            [
              -0.187989,
              51.502444
            ],
            [
              -0.191208,
              51.509869
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "properties": {
          "Territoire": 2
        }
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Hyde Park"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

you automatically got something like this:

[image: GeoJSON polygon with hole]

If you didn't have access to back-end where GeoJSON produced, and receive only polygons for target area you can add "whole map" part

```
[
    [
      -179.99,
      89.99
    ],
    [
      -179.99,
      0
    ],
    [
      -179.99,
      -89.99
    ],
    [
      0,
      -89.99
    ],
    [
      179.99,
      -89.99
    ],
    [
      179.99,
      0
    ],
    [
      179.99,
      89.99
    ],
    [
      0,
      89.99
    ],
    [
      -179.99,
      89.99
    ]
]
```

into position 0 (before coordinates of target area) of `coordinates` array of Polygon by code like that:

```
JSONObject featureCollection = geoJsonData;
JSONArray features = featureCollection.getJSONArray("features");
for(int i = 0; i < features.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject feature = features.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject geometry = feature.getJSONObject("geometry");
    String geometryType = geometry.getString("type");
    if ("Polygon".equals(geometryType)) {
        JSONArray coordinates = geometry.getJSONArray("coordinates");
        if (coordinates.length() == 1) {
            coordinates.put(coordinates.get(0));
            JSONArray wholeMap = new JSONArray(
                    "[\n" +
                            "            [\n" +
                            "              -179.99,\n" +
                            "              89.99\n" +
                            "            ],\n" +
                            "            [\n" +
                            "              -179.99,\n" +
                            "              0\n" +
                            "            ],\n" +
                            "            [\n" +
                            "              -179.99,\n" +
                            "              -89.99\n" +
                            "            ],\n" +
                            "            [\n" +
                            "              0,\n" +
                            "              -89.99\n" +
                            "            ],\n" +
                            "            [\n" +
                            "              179.99,\n" +
                            "              -89.99\n" +
                            "            ],\n" +
                            "            [\n" +
                            "              179.99,\n" +
                            "              0\n" +
                            "            ],\n" +
                            "            [\n" +
                            "              179.99,\n" +
                            "              89.99\n" +
                            "            ],\n" +
                            "            [\n" +
                            "              0,\n" +
                            "              89.99\n" +
                            "            ],\n" +
                            "            [\n" +
                            "              -179.99,\n" +
                            "              89.99\n" +
                            "            ]\n" +
                            "          ]"
            );
            coordinates.put(0, wholeMap);
        } else {
            Log.d("OAA", "No need insert");
        }
    }
}
```

where `geoJsonData` - your GeoJSON data without "whole map" part e.g.:

```
JSONObject geoJsonData = new JSONObject(
    "{\n" +
            "  \"type\": \"FeatureCollection\",\n" +
            "  \"features\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"type\": \"Feature\",\n" +
            "      \"geometry\": {\n" +
            "        \"type\": \"Polygon\",\n" +
            "        \"coordinates\": [\n" +
            "          [\n" +
            "            [\n" +
            "              -0.191208,\n" +
            "              51.509869\n" +
            "            ],\n" +
            "            [\n" +
            "              -0.158464,\n" +
            "              51.513287\n" +
            "            ],\n" +
            "            [\n" +
            "              -0.151769,\n" +
            "              51.50554\n" +
            "            ],\n" +
            "            [\n" +
            "              -0.174471,\n" +
            "              51.502178\n" +
            "            ],\n" +
            "            [\n" +
            "              -0.187989,\n" +
            "              51.502444\n" +
            "            ]\n" +
            "          ]\n" +
            "        ],\n" +
            "        \"properties\": {\n" +
            "          \"Territoire\": 2\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      \"properties\": {\n" +
            "        \"name\": \"Hyde Park\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  ]\n" +
            "}"
    );
```

**Update**
GeoJSON also supported polygon with multi "holes", that GeoJSON shows 2 "holes" for Hyde & Regent's Parks:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -179.99,
              89.99
            ],
            [
              -179.99,
              0
            ],
            [
              -179.99,
              -89.99
            ],
            [
              0,
              -89.99
            ],
            [
              179.99,
              -89.99
            ],
            [
              179.99,
              0
            ],
            [
              179.99,
              89.99
            ],
            [
              0,
              89.99
            ],
            [
              -179.99,
              89.99
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              -0.191208,
              51.509869
            ],
            [
              -0.158464,
              51.513287
            ],
            [
              -0.151769,
              51.50554
            ],
            [
              -0.174471,
              51.502178
            ],
            [
              -0.187989,
              51.502444
            ],
            [
              -0.191208,
              51.509869
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              -0.167685,
              51.530226
            ],
            [
              -0.163737,
              51.534924
            ],
            [
              -0.151849,
              51.537566
            ],
            [
              -0.151849,
              51.537566
            ],
            [
              -0.146914,
              51.535964
            ],
            [
              -0.145625,
              51.525325
            ],
            [
              -0.155538,
              51.523589
            ],
            [
              -0.167685,
              51.530226
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "properties": {
          "Territoire": 2
        }
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Hyde Park"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: this solution works well when the original geojson is a polygon. However, it doesn't when the geojson is originally a multipolygon.

For that case, I attempted to covert the Multipolygon to a polygon. This new polygon uses the world coordinates in position 0. I then add the polygons coordinates in positions 0+i ignoring holes. 

With this, the fill sometimes disappears.

Comment: @user1857437 It should be the one "mask" polygon (actually rectangle) for "whole world" in position 0 and other polygons should be added after it as "holes". It's impossible show "hole", described in one polygon, on another. Should be:` ["mask for whole world"], ["hole0"], ["hole1"],... ["holeN-1"]`.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://pastebin.com/HKqtUCxK) containing GeoJson for the city of Onion Creek, TX.  With this code, the city of Onion Creek is tinted while the map is normal color.
Here is a [link](https://pastebin.com/QBGhMUip) where the multi polygon GeoJson above has been converted to a polygon so that the whole map **should be** tinted and the area of Onion Creek, TX should be normal color. 

However it doesn't work. Is there an issue with my converted geojson or is there an issue with Google Maps v2 in Android. I think my converted geojson is correct.

Comment: I can't test your GeoJSON on device now, but GeoJSON on your second [link](https://pastebin.com/QBGhMUip) is 100% correct. I can test it n device on monday

Comment: Seems you are right: there an issue with Google Maps v2 in Android for GeoJSON polygon at least with narrow "holes" - it not correctly tinted for some cases.